# Writing to CloudAppendBlob: The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict & ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to understand what causes the **The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict** Exception.

I am writing lines to an AppendBlob by acquiring a lease, appending the text, and breaking the lease, like so. The error only happens every now and then, so I am curious what scenario would cause it to happen. My suspicion would be something may happen if multiple users hit the endpoint where this code executes and somehow to a call to acquire a lease happens at the same time.

```
// Get the AppendBlob reference
CloudAppendBlob blob = ….

// Acquire a lease on the blob until a call to breaking the lease is made
string leaseId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
await blob.AcquireLeaseAsync(null, leaseId);

// Append a new entry to the blob
await blob.AppendTextAsync(
       textToBeAppended,
       Encoding.UTF8,
       new AccessCondition { LeaseId = leaseId },
       new BlobRequestOptions(),
       new OperationContext());

// break the lease on the blob
await blob.BreakLeaseAsync(null);
```

The Failed Method is **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException.**

I see from telemetry that a call to PUT on the blob initially fails with the 409 status code and the exception above, but immediately after a successful PUT call with a 202 result code occurs. I'm assume Azure Storage is doing a retry, however I do not see the line of text in the file it was supposed to be appended to.

Here is the full call stack if that is helpful, I am not sure what the meaning of ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException is from this stack trace.

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:  at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 50)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass2`1.b__0
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Util\AsyncExtensions.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 69)
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   Microsoft.Community.Data.Providers.BlobStorageProvider+d__1.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   C:\BA\813\s\Microsoft.Community\Microsoft.Community.Data\Providers\BlobStorageProvider.csMicrosoft.Community.Data,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 67) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   Microsoft.Community.Data.Providers.BlobStorageProvider+d__1.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Community.Data, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   C:\BA\813\s\Microsoft.Community\Microsoft.Community.Data\Providers\BlobStorageProvider.csMicrosoft.Community.Data,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 72) at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
>   (mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089) at
>   Microsoft.Community.Web.Repositories.AzureMLRecommendationsRepository+d__6.MoveNext
>   (Microsoft.Community.Web, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Community.Web, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:
>   C:\BA\813\s\Microsoft.Community\Microsoft.Community.Web\Repositories\AzureMLRecommendationsRepository.csMicrosoft.Community.Web,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 95)
>
> Inner exception System.Net.WebException handled at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync:
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 54)
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob+<>c__DisplayClass39.b__38
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   3830) at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse
>   (Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage, Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.csMicrosoft.WindowsAzure.Storage,
>   Version=9.3.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35:
>   299)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wondering why you need to lease the blob and then append the text to the blob. If there are multiple writers simultaneously, it's **EXPECTED** that you'll meet (409) Conflict in your code.

As you can see in the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob), acquiring lease (B) when a blob is still being leased by lease (A) will encounter 409 error:
[image]

Basically, blob lease is to achieve exclusive write access on a blob, it's inappropriate to use blob lease if you want to append against a blob from multiple writers simultaneously.

**What are you afraid of if the AcquireLease and BreakLease operations are removed from your code? To be honest, I don't see any harm.**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like an issue with with concurrency possibly:
Breaks the lease, if the blob has an active lease. Once a lease is broken, it cannot be renewed. Any authorized request can break the lease; the request is not required to specify a matching lease ID. When a lease is broken, the lease break period is allowed to elapse, during which time no lease operation except break and release can be performed on the blob. When a lease is successfully broken, **the response indicates the interval in seconds until a new lease can be acquired.**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/lease-blob#outcomes-of-use-attempts-on-blobs-by-lease-state

---

If you look at link above you will see a huge table on how 409s can occur.
Can you run a fiddler to get the trace on inner exception?